# How to read from text file until string is found and delete text until next specific string is found?

Tags: php, string

My text file is:

```
;=-= title1-id1 =-=;
zzzzzzzzzzzz
xzqwnqrj90x9
n9ndfpo-f,m129
mf20fmf2-m,
;=-= end-title1-id1 =-=;

;=-= title2-id2 =-=;
zzzzzzzzzzzz
xzqwnqrj90x9
n9ndfpo-f,m129
mf20fmf2-m,
;=-= end-title2-id2 =-=;
```

I need to read this file and remove the content I want, for example: 
from `;=-= title2-id2 =-=;` until `;=-= end-title2-id2 =-=;`

Comment: Is it always the same format of date?

Comment: How big is the file? If it'll always be relatively small maybe you'd better read all of it into a string, do your cleaning there and write it back into the file.

Comment: @mariotanenbaum what date are you looking at? I don't see any dates.

Comment: it always the same format, it is the Asterisk extensions_custom.conf... it is a huge file

Comment: @Gil he means data-format

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents gets the whole file so its fills the memory.
I came up fast with something like this.

```
$myArray = array();  
$file = "file.txt";  
$bytesStreamed = 1024; //max line length times 8  
$tempString = "";  
$iterator = 1;  
$readCode = true;  

if($stream = fopen($file, 'r')) {  
    //stream_get_contents gets only few bytes of the file so does not use up all the memory for big files  
    while($streamKiloByte = stream_get_contents($stream, $bytesStreamed)) {  
        $temp = explode("\n", $tempString.$streamKiloByte);  
        $tempString = "";  
        for($i = 0; $i<(count($temp)-1); $i++){  
            if($i==0) {  
                //last element can be partial, lets keep it  
                $tempString = $temp[count($temp)-1];  
            } else {  
                array_push($myArray, $temp[$i-1]);  
            }  
        }  
        while(count($myArray)){  
            foreach($myArray AS $whatEver){  
                $firstElementOfArray = array_shift($myArray);  
                $f =& $firstElementOfArray;  
                if($f!="\r"){  
                     if($f ==";=-= title{$iterator}-id{$iterator} =-=;\r"){  
                        //the useless code started  
                        $readCode = false;  
                     } else if ($f == ";=-= end-title{$iterator}-id{$iterator} =-=;\r" || $f == ";=-= end-title{$iterator}-id{$iterator} =-=;"){  
                        //the useless code ended, preapered for next block  
                        $readCode = true;  
                        $iterator++;  
                     } else {  
                        if($readCode){  
                            //THE CODE  
                            echo $f;  
                        } else {  
                            //the useless code
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    fclose($stream);  
}
```

Used it on a file:

```
;=-= title1-id1 =-=;  
zzzzzzzzzzzz  
xzqwnqrj90x9  
n9ndfpo-f,m129  
mf20fmf2-m,  
;=-= end-title1-id1 =-=;  

THE CODE 1  

;=-= title2-id2 =-=;  
zzzzzzzzzzzz  
xzqwnqrj90x9  
n9ndfpo-f,m129  
mf20fmf2-m,  
;=-= end-title2-id2 =-=;  

THE CODE 2  

;=-= title3-id3 =-=;  
zzzzzzzzzzzz  
xzqwnqrj90x9  
n9ndfpo-f,m129  
mf20fmf2-m,  
;=-= end-title3-id3 =-=;  

THE CODE 3  

;=-= title4-id4 =-=;  
zzzzzzzzzzzz  
xzqwnqrj90x9  
n9ndfpo-f,m129  
mf20fmf2-m,  
;=-= end-title4-id4 =-=;
```

Had a resoult:

```
THE CODE 1THE CODE 2THE CODE 3
```

P.S. Stream THE CODE to a file so it wount take memory.

Comment: it just removes the last line, but i need to remove all lines between this to so-named "tags": ;=-= title2-id2 =-=; until ;=-= end-title2-id2 =-=;

Comment: Is the block body always 4 lines long? What do you want to do with the block content?

Comment: Oh. I have the wrong idea here. Sorry. Let me think and redo the code.

Comment: There you are. I think this can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own script, but i am afraid it needs optimization... However it works fine:

```
<?php
$filename = 'file.txt';
$fisttag = ';=-= title2-id2 =-=;';
$lasttag = ';=-= end-title2-id2 =-=;';
// Open the file
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}

$i=0;
$f = 0;
$newcont = "";
$blp = 0;

while(isset($array[$i]))
{
   //if(($array[$i]=="\n")and($array[$i+1]=="\n")){$blp=1;die($blp);}
   if($array[$i]==$fisttag){ $f=1; }
   if($f==1){ if($array[$i]==$lasttag){ $f=0; } }
   if(($f!=1)and($array[$i]!=$lasttag))
   {
    if($i>0 and ($array[$i-1]==$lasttag)){ $blp=1; }
    if($blp!=1){$newcont .= $array[$i]."<br />";}
    else $blp = 0;

   }
   $i++;
}

echo $newcont;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your **target**? and ask yourself do i have any other solution to achieve it.
by the way, using the files isn't the proper way, if you ask me & you don't have many options.
In this file you can search a part of your file content and then after submit, your searching result will be removed.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="searching">
<p>
    for example= insert "zzzzzzzzzzzz"
</p>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['searching']))
{
$file = 'test.txt';
$searchfor = $_POST['search'];

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
   $action = str_replace($searchfor, '', $contents);
   file_put_contents($file, $action);
}
}
```